# Jquery opacity change

Tags: jquery, opacity

I have this code:

```
$('a[rel="imagesHandler"]').hover(
    function(){
        //ia latimea
        var liWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).append('<div id="editBar"><a id="delPic" href="#"><img id ="piDe"src="./images/pic_del_icon.png" alt="" /></a></div>');

        $('div#editBar')
            .css({  'width':liWidth - 3,
                'height':'19px',
                'padding-left':'3px',
                'padding-top':'1px',
                'float':'left',
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'-22px',
                'z-index':200,
                'background-color':'black',
                'opacity':'0.5'
            })
            .hide()
            .fadeIn('slow');

        $('a#delPic').click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert('gigi');
            return false;
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('div#editBar').hide('slow');
        $('div#editBar').remove();
    }
);
```

So, i append that  that pops on mouseover, inside this div is the a#delPic. I changed the opacity of div#editBar to 0.5 but it applies to a#delPic too. So, I want to change back the a#delPic opacity to 1. How can I do this? I tried some versions. That's why I ended up putting that id to the anchor (trying to directly select it), but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opacity will be applied to all elements inside, you are not able to change this behaviour. But you can do a little trick:

```
$('a[rel="imagesHandler"]').hover(
function(){
    var liWidth = $(this).width();

    $(this).append('<div id="editBar"><div class="transparent"></div><a id="delPic" href="#"><img id ="piDe"src="./images/pic_del_icon.png" alt="" /></a></div>');

    $('div#editBar .transparent').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left':'0',
        'right':'0',
        'top':'0',
        'bottom':'0',
        'background-color':'black',
        'opacity':'0.5'
    });

    $('div#editBar').css({'width':liWidth - 3,
        'height':'19px',
        'padding-left':'3px',
        'padding-top':'1px',
        'float':'left',
        'position':'relative',
        'top':'-22px',
        'z-index':200
    }).hide().fadeIn('slow');

    $('a#delPic').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('gigi');
    return false;
    });
},

function(){
    $('div#editBar').hide('slow');
    $('div#editBar').remove();
}
```

);

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Setting opacity on an element makes everything inside it follow that rule. One solution (not widely implemented yet) is to use `rgba(r,g,b,o)` which will set opacity for that one element alone.

Another solution is to create a black 1px png 8 (also supported in IE6) or gif that's 50% opaque. Set this as the background-image for the parent element, and you're good to go.

Comment: ouh...so i have to change my strategy.. thanks for the answer guys

Comment: Arent GIF's either transparent or not?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the a tag is within the div, when you apply an opacity change to an element it will affect all elements within it too.